# rand() genera el mismo numero en ciclo

Tags: c++, random

El problema qeue intento solucionar es el por que en el programa no se genera mas de un numero aleatorio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int seed;
    int can = 0, num = 0, malo = 0;
    cout<<"Cantidad de jugadores (max. 50)"<<endl;
    cin>> can;
    if(can <= 50)
    {
        do{
            cout<<"Seleccione numero malo (1 - 6)"<<endl;
            cin>> malo;
        }while(malo > 7 && malo < 0);
        int players[can];
        for(int i = 0; i < can; i++ )
        {
            seed = time(0);
            srand(seed);
            num = rand() % (6 - 1);
            players[i] = num;
            cout<<"Jugador " << i + 1 <<" Numero: " << num;
            if(num == malo)
            {
                cout<<". Tu numero es el malo"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<". Tu numero es bueno"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ya he intentado usar

```
seed = time(NULL)
```

y no se pueden generar un numero diferente al inciail.

Muchas gracias por su atencion

Comment: Pues a mi [me funciona bien](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JQ2t9oVmSGSSKPvi). Voto por cerrarla como *no se puede reproducir*.

Comment: En cualquier caso no veo sentido a reiniciar la semilla en cada iteración del bucle. Yo lo haría fuera. Cabe la posibilidad de que en tu sistema (vete a saber por qué) `time()` te retorne siempre lo mismo y entonces al reinciar la semilla al mismo valor, reinicias la secuencia de numeros aleatorios a la misma, en cada iteración del bucle.